# Photoshop text tool adds punctuation to the beginning of text

Tags: photoshop

I have this weird issue with Photoshop - when I use the type tool, I can type letters normally, but when I type any punctuation character, it gets added to the beginning of the text.

As far as I remember, I haven't changed any settings. How do I avoid this ?

Comment: This does not really sound like a programming question. Might have better luck at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This was very helpful to me: http://thedigitalhippies.com/digital/photoshop-cs6-text-glitching-fixing-the-text-corruption-problem/#comment-3655

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try :
go to edit>preferencec>type..
select type > choose text engine options select east asian.
Restart photoshop.
Create new peroject.
Try text tool again.

(if you want to use your project created with other text engine type) copy /paste all layers to new project.

Comment: Weird, in CS5 I don't see the "text engine options". My "smart quotes" option is already selected but it still isn't working: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iOAAg.png

Answer (score 34):

This is a paragraph option. Go to Window>Paragraph then a small window will pop up. You will have two buttons on the bottom. One with a arrow on the left of P and one on the right. Select the right one.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, the most easy, without copy pasting layers between projects.

Comment: In Photoshop CC 2017 this option is available by clicking the little additional menu icon at the top right of the Paragraph window and then "Latin and East Asian Layout".

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

Select all text afected by this issue:

Window -> Character, click the icon next to hide the Character Window, Middle Western Features and select
Left-to-right character direction.

Comment: Thanks man! It was so much annoying!

Comment: You are a life saver mate!

Comment: This answer helped in my case too. I am not sure why Left-to-right direction is not the Default direction (the option that was checked while I had issues), but I hope that question will be answered soon too.. Thanks!