# How to make punctuation go to end or sentence in photoshop CC?

Tags: photoshop

[Photoshop text tool adds punctuation to the beginning of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196780/photoshop-text-tool-adds-punctuation-to-the-beginning-of-text)

How to make punctuation go to end or sentence in photoshop CC?  if I type, "test!" the result will be "!test".  How can I fix this for version CC?  everything I found seems to be for cs6 or another version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to Edit - Preferences Type... - Middle and South Asian -  "OK" - and restarted photoshop.  Then I went to Type - Language options - choose Middle Eastern Features (for some reason it was on Default here but still Middle Eastern under preferences. I don't know why I had to do it twice.)  and then Type - Language options - choose left - to - right character direction and voila! my punctuation stays to the right of my text.  I'm shocked this wasn't set by default BUT once i did change the settings the normal P for paragraph symbol reappeared in the paragraph panel.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, all I did was change the settings for Language options---paragraph and clicked on the paragraph symbol pointed to the right and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Been using Pshop forever. Suddenly, my punctuation was positioning itself at the left of the sentence and my quote marks were backwards. I have no idea how this issue started, but the fix for me was simply: (menu bar) Type>Language Options>Left to Right Character Direction.